# Rejecting an API call if another one is currently running in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I'm writing an API that does a bunch of stuff to a database, including truncate some tables and then insert some records. The API is not for end customer use, it's merely something used to prep the DB a bit for some system tests. However, it's possible that it could be invoked twice by accident.

Is there some way to reject an API call (return 4xx let's say) for a certain controller endpoint if there's already another request on the same endpoint being served?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only one server handles the API you could use a Mutex with something like the following code inside the controller:

```
using (var mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(false,
    "Global\\{7B28AF1F-AB08-4A11-B109-0E58F40B23D4}")); // Replace GUID with your own
{
    if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
    {
        return new ConflictResult(); // 409
    }
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The server runs across various instances, so this doesn't really work. The real solution I'm going with is inserting a row into the db and using the existence of that row as a lock. But, yeah, this technically answers my question.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you should handle concurrency. May be this can be helpful for you [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: I knew _someone_ was going to answer with this. It's prototypical StackOverflow. I really don't need to handle concurrency here. Moreover, I have reason _not_ to - I share a physical Snowflake for the logical dev and qa non prod environments, and the non prod instance has a scaffolded empty DB for testing migrations. I run these system tests in that DB because it's always up to date and always empty. It's not worth it to me to rig up two entire DBs in non prod just for this when I already have one carved for testing other things.

Comment: Well if the answer is not what you are looking for , there is no need to downvote since you already knew you can have this kind of answer due the nature of your questions. You should said in you question that concurrency is not what you want.

Comment: It's a downvote because the question specifically was "how can solve problem x?", not "what alternatives are there for me when I'm facing problem x?"